# How can I give my Flask Apache WSGI App permission to write/append to a file?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I am writing a small Flask web-application hosted on an Apache Server running Ubuntu 14. There is a feedback section on the website where one can visit and submit a feedback message which will then be sent to the server, and appended to a text file. Here is the `new_feedback` method:

```
def new_feedback(name, message):
    file = open('feedback.txt', "a")
    file.write(name + '  wrote:  ' + message + '\n'+'***********************************'+'\n\n')
    file.close()
```

However, when the method is called, the Apache server gives the following error in the `error.log` file.

```
File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/feedback.py", line 2, in new_feedback
[Sat Dec 05 13:15:02.825594 2015] [:error] file = open('feedback.txt', "a")
[Sat Dec 05 13:15:02.825601 2015] [:error] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'feedback.txt'
```

One way I have attempted to debug this, is to run it locally, which has absolutely no issues on my Windows computer. In other words, the logic seems to be alright. Thanks!

Comment: Read https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory and https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks a ton, the first article was a great read! I actually had to have the absolute file path rather than the relative - How would I go about setting the first article as the answer to this question?